# Prolog BattleShips bombing game

Tags: prolog

So i'm programming a battleship game in prolog. The game has 5x5 board where ships should be located with similar logic to real game, which means they can't be side by side and touch each other at all.

So i've came across these problems.

1. How to make the code recognize which board Tiles(cordinates) have been already shot?
2. How can i programmatically recognize ships as a whole and how to use this knowledge to recognize when the ship has sank.

Currently the prompt loop will end after first hit, but goal is to end the loop when all ships are sank.

**EDIT: Board contains 2 values 0 and 1, 0 is empty Tile, 1 represents that it has an ship part on it.**

```
board([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]).

row_at(X, Row) :-
  board(Board),
  nth0(X, Board, Row).

column_at(Y, Row, Cell) :-
  nth0(Y, Row, Cell).

ship_at(X, Y) :-
  row_at(X, Row),
  column_at(Y, Row, Cell),
  Cell = 1.

hit:-
    write('hit!'), nl.

miss :-
    write('miss!'), nl.

target(X, Y, State) :-
  (ship_at(X, Y) ->
    hit, asserta(X,Y);
    miss).

prompt_number(Prompt, Number) :-
  write(Prompt),
  write(': '),
  read(Number).

:- initialization(main).
main :-
  repeat,
  prompt_number('enter column number', Col),
  prompt_number('enter row number', Row),
  target(Row, Col, State),
  (ship_at(Row, Col) ->
    write('you won!'), nl, halt ;
    write('keep trying!'), nl, fail).
```

Comment: In answer to your questions, you need to decide upon a representation of the data (the board coordinates). There are probably several ways to do this. Your current code has a 1 or 0 in each location, which you haven't explained (does a 1 mean it's shot? or a ship is there?). Since you have two independent pieces of information per grid location (whether there's a ship there, or whether that position has been shot) then you need two values per location to tell you what's going on.

Comment: Added the comment, thanks for noticing :)

Comment: To restate the important part of my prior comment, 1 and 0 are not adequate to describe the state of a position in the matrix. The state must be able to indicate *what* ship is there (if any, assuming there is more than one), and whether or not that position has been hit.

Comment: I was thinking about making another list of bombed spots, and then i could check if there was a part of ship. But don't know how to really use lists in prolog in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way. As I mentioned before, for each position, you have two independent variables to keep track of. One is the ship, if any, occupying the position, and second is whether that position has been hit. These attributes could be encoded into a single item, or more clearly maintained separately. If separate, they could be in completely different structures, or be in a tuple in the same structure. Lots of choices.

Comment: Could you provide me a sample interaction which includes the bombed spots memorizing considering the code i already have?